# HTML Image is Not Loading in Any Browser

Tags: html, image

my image is not appearing on my site when my page loads, in any browser. My HTML code is

```
<HTML>
<img class="header-img" src="images/headerbanner.png" alt="App Image" />
</HTML>
```

The size and width of the div holding this are set in a css file. The images folder is located in the same directory as the file making this img tag call. However, whenever my page loads, the image appears with an icon in the middle, with no image showing, and only the alternate text. I cannot figure out the problem, and any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The width of the image is 1000px, and the height is 300px. The css code sets the width of this tag in the header-img class.

To clarify, I have double checked the image name, and it is headerbanner.png, located in an images folder, which is in the same folder as the file with the image tag. The image div tag is larger than the image, but I don't think that would be a problem. This is a wordpress site running off of a local MAMP server.

Comment: specify width of the image

Comment: The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Probably the URL just doesn’t point an image resource. The problem cannot be resolved with the given data – we cannot see what you actually have on the server.

Comment: Is there any entry in error log of your webserver? Add a body- Tag arround the image.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Find the HTTP request for the image. Look at the response. The error code will help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You said the alternative text is showing, but the code you have provided doesn't have any alternative text. You should provide code that actually demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t see an image and see an icon only, there are these possibilities:

- images is in another folder
- `images` folder is located elsewhere
- image has another name (filenames are case-sensitive)
- image isn´t on your server
- image can be broken

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a WordPress template ? Are this code is part of WordPress template?

If so, you should use `get_template_directory_uri();` WordPress function to retrieve the absolute url of your images, then it will work.

Look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri